# Use tsql partition by twice in one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partition

I have a table with fields of group 1, group 2 and date.

If I run this query I get the result below:

```
SELECT 
   [group1]
  ,[group2]
  ,[date]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by [group1] order by [date]) as ord
FROM [dev_DP].[dbo].[myTable]

+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+
| group1 | group2 |          date           | ord |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+
| dan    | alarm  | 2014-05-14 12:00:00.000 |   1 |
| dan    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:30:00.000 |   2 |
| dan    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:50:00.000 |   3 |
| jim    | snooze | 2014-05-14 11:00:00.000 |   1 |
| jim    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:45:00.000 |   2 |
| jim    | alarm  | 2014-05-14 13:45:00.000 |   3 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+-----+
```

I want to add another column which then adds a row number to the table based on the group 1 and group 2 field but retains the date order just for group 1.  The results I want are below:

```
+--------+--------+---------------------+-----+------+
| group1 | group2 |        date         | ord | ord2 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+-----+------+
| dan    | alarm  | 2014-05-14 12:00:00 |   1 |    1 |
| dan    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:30:00 |   2 |    1 |
| dan    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:50:00 |   3 |    2 |
| jim    | snooze | 2014-05-14 11:00:00 |   1 |    1 |
| jim    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:45:00 |   2 |    2 |
| jim    | alarm  | 2014-05-14 13:45:00 |   3 |    1 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+-----+------+
```

How can I do this?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: If you're executing the query in SSMS, change the result output setting to "Results to Text" and paste the results after your code. As-is, this is extremely difficult to parse visually.

Comment: Sorry - should have checked it first. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the second results is what you want? I can't spot a obvious pattern in the values of `ord2`.

Comment: yes - I'm sure - so the idea is I want to get the first in a sequence of 'alarms' and the first in a sequence of 'snoozes' for a given group1. To do this group 1 had to be grouped then ordered on date.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT 
  [group1]
  ,[group2]
  ,[date]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by [group1] order by [date]) as ord1
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by [group1], [group2] order by [date]) as ord2
  FROM [dev_DP].[dbo].[myTable]
```

Comment: This is nearly what I want but it isn't ordered by date. What I need is it grouped by group 1 then ordered by date, then row_number of group 2.

Answer (score 0):

If I switch those terms around:

```
  SELECT 
  [group1]
  ,[group2]
  ,[date]

  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by [group1], [group2] order by [date]) as ord2
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by [group1] order by [date]) as ord1
  FROM [dev_DP].[dbo].[myTable]
```

I thought this gives me the result I wanted but it doesn't...If I add another record you can see the error.

```
+--------+--------+-------------------------+------+------+
| group1 | group2 |          date           | ord2 | ord1 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+------+------+
| dan    | alarm  | 2014-05-14 12:00:00.000 |    1 |    1 |
| dan    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:30:00.000 |    1 |    2 |
| dan    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:50:00.000 |    2 |    3 |
| dan    | alarm  | 2014-05-14 13:00:00.000 |    2 |    4 |
| jim    | snooze | 2014-05-14 11:00:00.000 |    1 |    1 |
| jim    | snooze | 2014-05-14 12:45:00.000 |    2 |    2 |
| jim    | alarm  | 2014-05-14 13:45:00.000 |    1 |    3 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+------+------+
```